# How to pass a custom component to title props in MUI tooltip?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to customize a [Tooltip](https://mui.com/components/tooltips/#main-content) component by passing a custom component like the image.

[image]

At first time, I've used [Popover](https://mui.com/components/popover/#main-content) once, but the main reason why I am going to use Tooltip is because of the arrow of Tooltip.

Basically, I am using React and MUI v5 running on TypeScript.

I built a custom Tooltip component like this.

```
    <Tooltip
      open={open}
      arrow
      placement={placement}
      title={
        <Box component="span" p={1} width={width}>
          <IconButton size="small" onClick={onClose}>
            <CloseIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Box my={2} px={4}>
            <Typography my={2}>
              {message}
            </Typography>
            <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox defaultChecked />} label="Don’t show again" />
          </Box>
        </Box>
      }
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </Tooltip>
```

It seems to be working, but it keeps saying an error message `Tooltip title. Zero-length titles string are never displayed. 'title' is specified more than once, so this usage will be overwritten.ts(2783)`.

How can I resolve this issue, or should I use Popover rather than Tooltip component?

[image]

Comment: Try to move `title` prop after `{...rest}`. does it help?

Comment: @m51 Wow, that's it? It was a magic. Thanks! Can it be an answer with some helpful description? I can tick then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `title` prop after `{...rest}` parameters.

It looks like your `rest` paramaters already have `title` property inside, so basically you are overwriting your `title` with something else from rest parameters (at least typescript thinks that).

It is the same as:

```js
const foo = { title: 'aaaa', sth: 'cccc' };

const bar = { title: 'bbbb', ...foo}

console.log(bar.title); // => 'aaaa'
```

If you open this code in some environment with typescript support, it will also show same error as yours, see

[image: Edit TypeScript Playground Export]

What you need to do is:

```js
const foo = { title: 'aaaa', sth: 'cccc' };

const bar = { ...foo, title: 'bbbb' };

console.log(bar.title); // => 'bbbb'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can pass custom compoenent as title props in the following way

```
import { withStyles } from '@mui/material/styles'
import WarningRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/WarningRounded'
import CheckCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckCircle'
import ErrorIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Error'
import Alert from '@mui/material/alert'
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip'
import classnames from 'classnames'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'
import styles from './styles'


const Component = ({
    classes,
    message,
    status
}) => {

    const LightTooltip = withStyles(theme => ({
        tooltip: {
            borderRadius: '2px',
            fontSize: 12,
            padding: 0,
            width: '300px',
        },
    }))(Tooltip)

    const CustomTooltipComponent = ({status, color, message, icon}) => (<LightTooltip
        arrow
        placement={'top'}
        title={
            <Alert severity={status} style={{ border: `1px solid ${color}`}} >
                <strong>{status.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + status.slice(1)} : </strong>{message.join(', ')}
            </Alert>
        }
    >
        {icon}
    </LightTooltip>)

    const RenderValidated = isValidated => {
        switch (isValidated) {
            case 'success':
                return (<CustomTooltipComponent
                    status={isValidated}
                    color={'green'}
                    icon={<CheckCircleIcon className={classnames(classes.icon, classes.success)}/>}
                    message={[ 'Request row has been submitted' ]}
                />)
            case 'error':
                return (<CustomTooltipComponent
                    status={isValidated}
                    color={'red'}
                    icon={<ErrorIcon className={classes.icon} color='error'/>}
                    message={message}
                />)
            case 'warning':
                return (<CustomTooltipComponent
                    status={isValidated}
                    color={'orange'}
                    icon={<WarningRoundedIcon className={classes.icon} color='warning'/>}
                    message={message}
                />)
        }
    }

    return RenderValidated(status)
}

Component.displayName = 'ValidatedFramework'
Component.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.shape({
        icon: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        success: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }),
    message: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
    status: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Component)
```